# How the switch between two mobile apps occurs in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I have a customer that wants to include an icon that will switch between two apps. As an example, Lets say Facebook app have an icon that takes you to messenger and the same from Messinger to Facebook. How is this possible when you have two independent native apps or one hybrid and one native?

Comment: In Android, a click event on your icon would trigger a call to `startActivity()`, where you start an activity of the other app.

Comment: Same mechanism (different implementation) exists in iOS

Answer (score 1):

If you know the package name of the application you want to open, then you can follow this code. Package name looks something like this. `"com.google.android.maps.mytracks"`

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (i == null) {
   return false;
   //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
}
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
context.startActivity(i);
```